# How to put text under a big bracket

Tags: positioning, brackets

I have this

How can i do this ?
[image]

[image]

Here is my code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
$ \dot{\partial}W(v)=\Bigg\{ v^*\in \mathbb{R}^j :$ lim inf $ \frac{W(z) - W(v) - \langle v^*,z - v  \rangle} {\| z - v \|} \geq 0 \Bigg\} $ \\ 
\vspace{2mm}
\hspace{3,6cm}$ z\to v $ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is your question about how to place `z\to v` below `lim inf`?

Comment: Loading the `amsmath` package provides access to a macro called `\liminf`; its output is what's shown in the lower screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you after what @Mico guess in his comment:

[image]

Using `mathtools` package for defining `\norm` delimiters, your equation can be written as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\[
\dot{\partial }W(v)
    = \Biggl\{ v^*\in \mathbb{R}^j : \liminf_{z\to v} 
        \frac{W(z) - W(v) - \langle v^*,z - v \rangle}{\norm{z - v}} 
        \geq 0  \Biggr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
or you prefer the following very unusual form?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\dot{\partial }W(v)
    = \Biggl\{ v^*\in \mathbb{R}^j : \liminf 
        \frac{W(z) - W(v) - \langle v^*,z - v \rangle}{\norm{z - v}} 
        \geq 0  \Biggr\} \\
        z\to v  
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The first `\Bigg` should be `\Biggl` and the other one `\Biggr`.

Comment: @egreg, yo are right. I blindly copied OP code fragment. Corrected now.

Comment: I would actually argue that one can get away with smaller fences here because the fences are a bit way from the tall/deep material. `\Bigl ... \Bigr` looks fine to me.